# Trying to remember the name of a UML Diagramming Tool that saves its files as HTML/SVG

Tags: uml

I have used a tool that ran as a client application. It allowed for most UML Diagrams. It saved these diagrams as HTML/SVG. I cannot remember the name of the tool. So I am reaching out to the hive mind to see if anyone else remembers this tool (or is using it now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a diagram that I had made with the tool.  Looking at the source I was able to find the product name.  It was referenced in a comment in the source.  It is called violet and can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/
Unfortunately, it appears to be a dead project.  Too bad I like the fact that it is lightweight and consumers of your diagrams need nothing beyond a fairly current browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try digging for alternatives on [draw.io](https://alternativeto.net/software/diagramly/) her. It might be draw.io, i know it saves in either XML or HTML format, not necessarily sure about the .SVG though